# Upgraded C# / ASP.NET MVC project from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 8.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-8.0, .net-4.7.2

I have upgraded an ASP.NET MVC project, written in C# and running on .NET 4.7.2, to .NET 8.0.

I get this error:

> The type or namespace name 'DirectoryServices' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have tried to install `System.ServiceModel.Primitive` and it didn't work.

The old code uses

```
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.ServiceModel;
```

Comment: Tried the [System.DirectoryServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.DirectoryServices) nuget?

Comment: I have tried System.DirectoryServices            {8.0.0}